# Create a chatbot with predefined question and answers in python?

Tags: python

I am new to creating chatbot.I have a questions and answers list.By using those i have to create a chatbot.

```
Sample User inputs here
['Hi','What is my commission','Yes',31289,'Are you sure?','Yes' ]
```

```
chatbot response here
['Hi Jordan, welcome to the agent point center. How can I help you today?','Would you like to know your commission for 2019?','Can you help me with your NPN number?','Your unpaid commission for 2019 is $ 4280 for 10 contracts. In 2018, your total paid commission was $45200']
```

Please,guide me how to create a chatbot with above question and answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the users will input *exactly* the predefined questons, you can use:

```
questions = {"sample_question": "sample_answer", "sample_question2": "sample_answer2"}
q = input("What is your question? ")
while len(q) > 0:
    print(questions[q])
    q = input("What is your question? ")
```

This will ask questions and print the responses until they press return with no input.

Comment: Can you explain why you included ```q=input("What is your question?")```

Comment: That part asks the user to enter their question and then saves it to a variable.

Comment: Some inputs are not questions so maybe a simple prompt would be better than "What is your question?"

Comment: That's because the input needs to exactly match the question. However, if you define all your questions in lower case, and add `.lower()` to the ends of all the inputs, you can normalise all the text to lowercase.

Comment: Is other method exists than creating dictionary?

Comment: @Jammy , I have created dictionary with inputs and responses but having two same keys with different values. while executing it is giving second input value.How to get accurate answer for the inputs ?